# The unity console claims that the variable temp is declared but never used

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class GameBoardScript : MonoBehaviour {

    public int m_size;
    public GameObject m_PuzzlePiece;

    void Start() {
        GameObject temp;

        for (int i = 0; i < m_size; i++) {

            for (int j = 0; j<m_size; j++) {
                temp = (GameObject)Instantiate(m_PuzzlePiece, new Vector2(i*400/m_size, j*400/m_size), Quaternion.identity);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: double click on the warning in the console and make sure it goes to this script. You might have another variable somewhere else called temp that is causing the warning.

Comment: It's going to this script.

Comment: While it's good practice to try and fix warnings within your code, they normally shouldn't interfere with the running of your game. This particular warning is simply showing redundancies in your code (which on a larger-scale project may cause problems with you using too much memory).

Answer (score 2):

The reason you get this warning is because you **assign** the variable. But you don't **use** the variable of `temp`. Do anything with the variable after it's deceleration and the warning will go away! For example:

```
for (int i = 0; i < m_size; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j<m_size; j++) 
    {
        temp = (GameObject)Instantiate(m_PuzzlePiece, new Vector2(i*400/m_size, j*400/m_size), Quaternion.identity);
        temp.SetActive(false); // this is an arbitrary use of temp. don't actually do this
    }
}
```

Joe Blow is right that you should just call instantiate without assigning it's return to a variable if you don't intend to do anything to the instantiated `GameObject` afterwards. However just declaring the variable local to the inner for loop will still **not** remove the warning if you still fail to use it.

---

**Please Note** The compiler doesn't work out that the `m_size` variable could be 0 and might not reach the inner for loop. The warning occurrs because the line

```
temp = (GameObject)Instantiate(m_PuzzlePiece, new Vector2(i*400/m_size, j*400/m_size), Quaternion.identity);
```

is an **assignment** not a **use** of the variable `temp`. You could assign it as many times as you want and you will still get the same warning. You need to either **use** it or not assign the returned `GameObject` from `Instantiate` to a variable at all.